# Concurrent hashmap scalability with multiple JVM

Tags: java, concurrency

Current implementation:

There is a queue from which messages are pushed to a component, From where the messages are placed in a DB and are processed further. It involved many DB calls and takes more time also. So need to modify this by a different approach.

One such solution is : Having a concurrent Hashmap with key as header id and value as Concurrent linked queue of messages.

1. Dispatcher – Segregates the incoming messages based on their header id and place them in a ConcurrentHashMap with key as the id and value in ConcurrentLinkedQueue.
2. Worker – Worker thread is a scheduled thread that will invoke the processor with the specified time delay repeatedly. It sends the individual queue grouped under each header id to the processor through the executor. Once a particular header id is empty in the map, it removes it.
3. Processor – Polls the messages one by one from the queue(ConcurrentLinkedQueue) and processes it.

Also, one of my colleague comments as "The approach should be scalable as we are accounting for another instance of the component running from a different host"

Please throw some light on this. How this can be done? Any direction or link or any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid that this Question doesn't make much sense to me.  Any solution with a single `ConcurrentHashMap` does not "scale" beyonds a single JVM.  Conversely, when you go to multiple JVMs the components need to talk to each other. You need to specify where the various components are and how they communicate, before anyone can comment on performance issues.

Comment: The proposed solution is for single JVM only. But in future there could be a possibility that one more server could be added. In that case, how to make this work? some thing like having the map in cache etc..Or I am afraid the solution is completely wrong?

Comment: Well, the point is that going from one JVM to multiple JVMs is a significant re-architecture.  You make it work .... in the standard way; i.e. by having clients and servers sending requests and replies, or a message queuing system (MQ / Tivoli, JMS, etc).  There are whole books on this topic ...

Comment: For the single JVM case, what you are proposing is not unreasonable.  However, the performance will depend on things like average and peak request rates, typical time taken to process a request, etcetera.  These things are hard to measure, and harder to predict.  You are in the best place to make estimates, and do some calculations .... not us.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. Currently, there is one server sending messages to a messaging queue and the messages from the queue are pushed to a component from where they are placed in DB and processed further. Instead of having multiple DB calls, we want a different approach. Kindly throw some light..

Comment: Now your question is starting to make sense.  You should add those details to the Question, and someone will give you a proper Answer.  (Hint:  When you ask "will X be faster?", the counter-question is "faster than what?")

Comment: What I thought of is a "shared storage but of temporary nature". From the storage, the messages should be grouped and then processed parallely. 
One of my colleague comments "the approach should be scalable as we need to account for another instance of the component running from a different host."

Comment: Take a look at Redis

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something like Hazelcast (https://hazelcast.com/), eg http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.3/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html